# Regular Expression to match PO Box address

Tags: java, regex

I'm using this regular expression to catch  "PO Box" strings. This seems to work when I test it online but the javacode below is printing false. What mistake am I making?

> /^\s*((P(OST)?.?\s*(O(FF(ICE)?)?)?.?\s+(B(IN|OX))?)|B(IN|OX))/i

String to test - **PO Box 1234**

```
    String spattern = "/^\\s*((P(OST)?.?\\s*(O(FF(ICE)?)?)?.?\\s+(B(IN|OX))?)|B(IN|OX))/i";

    String regex = "PO Box 1234";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(spattern);

    System.out.println(pattern.matcher(regex).matches());
```

I've tested the expression online at http://regex101.com/ and it says there is match for the test string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your pattern like this:

```
String spattern = "(?i)^\\s*((P(OST)?.?\\s*(O(FF(ICE)?)?)?.?\\s+(B(IN|OX))?)|B(IN|OX))";
```

If you know you won't use your pattern often, you can try this instead:

```
String myInput = ....

if (myInput.matches(spattern)) {
     // myInput is a PO BOX ...
} else {
     // myInput isn't a PO BOX ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java you don't use the form `/regex/flags`. Instead you can do something like

```
Pattern.compile(regex, flags);
```

So remove `/` and `/i` and try with

```
String spattern = "^\\s*((P(OST)?.?\\s*(O(FF(ICE)?)?)?.?\\s+(B(IN|OX))?)|B(IN|OX))";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(spattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

You can also pass flags directly to regex string. Just add `(?i)` at the beginning for case insensitive regex. You can add this flag at any place, depending of scope it should affect. For instance if you place it like this `a(?i)a` regex will be able to match `aa` and `aA` but not `Aa` or `AA` because flag works from point between first and second `a`. Similarly `a((?i)a)a` will match `aaa` and `aAa` but will not match `AAa` nor `aAA` because `(?i)` affects only scope of group 1 (the part in parenthesis). More info at http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

---

Also, the `matches` method checks if *entire string* is matched by regex, not if string *contains* part that can be matched by regex. Maybe instead of `matches` use the `find` method like

```
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(regex).find());
```

Answer (score -1):

Regex to check the PO box address, specifically for USA addresses:

This works perfectly for me.

Java:

static final String thePattern = "(?i)([\w\s*\W]*(P(OST)?.?\s*((O(FF(ICE)?)?).?\s*(B(IN|OX|.?)))+))[\w\s*\W]*|(COMMUNITY\s*)?POST(AL)?\s*(OFF(ICE)?(\s*(BOX|BOZ|BX))?|(BOX|BX))|(^\s*(BOXOC|P\.?0\.?))";

Samples which the above regex will detect:

Post Office Bin : Valid

P O Box DesMoines1000 : Valid

1316  PO BOX Benjamin Street : Valid

P Browny House : Invalid

Community P Box : Invalid

P Boxting : Invalid

P Binter : Invalid

JavaScript:

var regex = /^([\w\s*\W]*(P(OST)?.?\s*((O(FF(ICE)?)?).?\s*(B(IN|OX|.?)))+))[\w\s*\W]*|(COMMUNITY\s*)?POST(AL)?\s*(OFF(ICE)?(\s*(BOX|BOZ|BX))?|(BOX|BX))|(^\s*(BOXOC|P.?0.?))$/i;